# parsing issue with loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

I am using webhook in my project. So webhook hit an endpoint that i created. When i used node js i used a `body-parser`. So it gives `req.body` as

```
"events":[],"firstEventSequence": 0,"lastEventSequence": 0, "entropy": "INYZZZJXMEHHCOCQNKWN"}
```

As here is space between `0` and `firstEventSequence`.

but in loopback when i convert `req.body` to `JSON.stringfy` i get as

```
"events":[],"firstEventSequence":0,"lastEventSequence":0,"entropy":"INYZZZJXMEHHCOCQNKWN"}
```

So here no spaces due to which hash of request body is different.
So what should i do so that loopback gives me request body similar to node js ?

Comment: does that _space_ matters as long as it is a valid `JSON`?

Comment: Space matters because i need to generate a hash.

Comment: will something like `JSON.stringify(products).split(',').join(', ')` work?

Comment: No this won't help @SalithaIndrajithPathiraja